# Javascript function invocation syntax unclear

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find a reference that describes the following syntax:

```
 func() ();
```

This invocation of func is at the end of a constructor. Other invocations within the constructor are 'normal'.

Comment: `func` returns a function when ran.  So, you're running `func()`, then running the function it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func()` returns a function, which is then invoked by the second set of `()`.

```
function func () {
  return function () {
    alert("ok!");
  }
}

func()(); // ok!
```

Comment: Thanks. Taking a closer look at the 'func' code, I see that is what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
func()();
```

is equivalent to:

```
var tempfunc = func();
tempfunc();
```

This is used for running a function that returns another function.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any confusion:
We know that functions get invoked like this:

```
functionName ();
```

So anything before the `()` is the function name,

In the case of `func() ()` put in mind that the `func()` is replacing the `functionName`, so this is also a function call, but even `func()` itself is a function, so we conclude that this is a function withing a function.

And for a more appropriate definition: `func() ()` is a function that has another function as its return value, and by doing this we are calling that returned function to be executed.

Comment: Right. I really need more sleep at night!